# Pass a function of window.onload inside styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently working on a sidebar that doesn't have a complete height. I'm trying to get the height of the header minus the height of the window screen.

```
const setSidebarHeight = () => {
    return (window.onload = () => {
        if (document.getElementById('navigation-bar')) {
            return ( window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('navigation-bar').clientHeight );
        }
    });
}

const SideBarDiv = styled.div`
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #f4f3f4;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    height: ${setSidebarHeight()}px;
`;
```

I have a question about about passing a `window.onload` to a css a attribute of `height` the current code doesn't show any px inside the devtools.

please help me about this. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

with the help of [`CSS#calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc),you can do dynamic height calculation.

use `view port` height

```
height : calc(100vh-20px) //20px height of header
```

Answer (score 0):

I not quite understand your question but I have a better way to do that

```
const setSidebarHeight = () => {
 return (window.onload = () => {
  if (document.getElementById('navigation-bar')) {
   return ( window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('navigation-bar').clientHeight );
  }
 });
};

render() {
  <SideBarDiv height={this.setSidebarHeight()} />
}

const SideBarDiv = styled.div`
 // ....
 height: ${props => props.height}px;
`;
```

Comment: this still returns a code in styles of `height: px` it renders two times. first render is `null` the second render is the html code of the `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

While RIYAJ KHAN answer elicits the best method, I will answer your original question.

You simply have to set a variable inside the onLoad method and refer to it in your component string.

```
var panelHeight = 0;
window.onload = () => {
        if (document.getElementById('navigation-bar')) {
             panelHeight = window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('navigation-bar').clientHeight ;
        }
}
```

Then...

```
const SideBarDiv = styled.div`
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #f4f3f4;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    height: ${panelHeight}px;
`;
```

Comment: this only returns a `height: 0` in styles of html devtools

Comment: Then your  `window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('navigation-bar').clientHeight` calculation is wrong.

Comment: this returns a number. which is correct, I don't know why the value doesn't return. :(

Comment: Ok. I get your problem. Now the thing is that  - by the time you refer to this variable, it is not updated. Put the `panelHeight = window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('navigation-bar').clientHeight ;` statement at the top of your first script tag in the html.